# cURL and wget with Tor

Tags: socks, proxy, information-leaks, proxy-leaks

What information about me (not the exit node) is revealed when a request originating from cURL / wget is proxied through Tor?

Example:

> curl https://example.com/ --socks5 localhost:9150 -H "User-Agent: "

I've looked through the headers (with no obvious personally identifiable information present), but I fear there may be some "hidden" information that cannot be seen (such as the IP address)

Note: Tags may not be accurate

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who here browses, answers and asks questions through Tor?

Answer (score 2):

They will know you're (likely) using curl, similarly they might know you're using wget or pythons urllib based on the behaviour and other headers. They might be able to guess at other aspects of the system, sometimes information like architecture can be sent in headers (x86_64, i386, arm, ..., etc), I've seen kernel versions and linux distro reported in user-agents too.

Your best option is to have a good anonymity set, e.g. to use curl from a debian jessie system and not try to hide the user-agent (this is something unique that you are doing, therefor making you less anonymous). This will give you the biggest crowd to hide in.

The requests themselves will not leak your own IP, with the exception of non-http protocols, for example if you try to use [ftp *active* mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Communication_and_data_transfer) you will send your IP address to the remote host as part of the normal protocol.